# xml parsing error with jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

Why do I get  `Invalid XML` when I parse with jquery xml

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var xml = '<?php echo XML_CONFIGS . '/feed_config.xml' ?>';
    $("#sql_config").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();  
     xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml ),
     $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
     $feed = $xml.find( "feed[id = 4]" );

     console.log($feed);
        var data = $('#sql').serialize();              
    });
```

The hosted xml http://ui.kakuki.de/feed_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <element>
        <feed id=" 4 ">
            <title>My Feed</title>
            <table>my_table</table>
            <link>http://testsite.com/export/export?myFeed=13&amp;myFormat=134251570</link>
            <feed_type>XML</feed_type>
        </feed>
        <query/>
    </element>
</config>
```

Comment: The XML you provided is valid. I guess, it differs from the one, stored in the `xml` variable.

Comment: I've been validating the hole xml and seems to be okay

Comment: Debug your code to see, if the value stored in `xml` variable is valid XML document.

Comment: Host the xml  and share the link for that. It will be easier for us to see what's going wrong ...

Comment: okay thanks I going to do that!

Comment: All seems valid to me but your `$xml.find` will return an empty array as your id isn't `4` its `" 4 "`  eg. `"feed[id=\"4\"]"`

Comment: What browser are you using also?

Comment: @Lavabeams thanks for your feedback, if you post your comment as answer I accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$.parseXML(xml)` and XML all seems fine and loads for me in all browsers I have tested with.

However your `$xml.find` will return an empty array as your `id` is incorrect.

Your `id` isn't `4` its `" 4 "` so your find should be `$xml.find("feed[id=\" 4 \"]")`

Glad I could help.